# C++ optimize array conversion from int to float

Tags: c++, matlab, tbb, intel-mkl

I'm trying to speed up some Matlab code by porting it to C++, and I've discovered that very simple operations are much slower in C++ than in Matlab. Namely, converting an array of integers to floats. I'm using Intel Parallel Studio 2018 with MKL and TBB.

This line in Matlab takes an average of 6 ms on my laptop (Mac OS 10.13):

`spec = single(spec_int); % spec_int is 1000x4096 uint16`

The naive approach (single loop) takes about 9 ms (excluding memory allocation and initialization):

```
uint16_t *spec_int = (uint16_t *) MKL_malloc(4096 * 1000 * sizeof(uint16_t), 64);
float *spec = (float *) MKL_malloc(sizeof(float) * FRAME_SIZE, 64);

// Initialize spec_int

for(MKL_INT i = 0; i<FRAME_SIZE; i++)
    spec[i] = spec_int[i];
```

With `parallel_for` in TBB it takes about 13 ms:

```
tbb::parallel_for( size_t(0), size_t(FRAME_SIZE), [&]( size_t i ) {
    spec[i] = spec_int[i];
} );
```

I'm puzzled. What am I doing wrong? How can I match Matlab speed in C++?

Comment: It is very possible that your naive approach is being vectorized by the compiler.  What optimization level are you using when compiling?

Comment: I can't imagine the parallel version would be faster unless the vector was huge

Comment: You should certainly use an `int` for the loop variables and index, rather than any other type such as `MKL_INT`, whatever it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver -O3. Yes, there's probably automatic vectorization. This is the full compile line: icc -DMKL_ILP64 -mkl=parallel -O3 -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/mkl/include -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/tbb/include -std=c++11 -o gdocm_cpu main.cpp -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/mkl/lib -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/tbb/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/mkl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.041/mac/tbb/lib -ltbb -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -ldl

Comment: @RichardHodges Intel documentation states: "Typically a loop needs to take at least a million clock cycles to make it worth using parallel_for. For example, a loop that takes at least 500 microseconds on a 2 GHz processor might benefit from parallel_for." I have 4 million elements or so, and the loop takes 9ms. So I was expecting at least some improvement.

Comment: @EJP MKL_INT is just an alias for the correct integer type to index vectors. I get the same results if I use size_t or int for the counter.

Comment: @Wolfy - Based on that documentation and your results (no improvement), that kind of reinforces my answer, which is that memory IO (or something related) is likely to be the limiting factor for this loop..because of course parallel processing is not going to speed that up.  For something more complex, like a transform, that's less likely to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:  You are probably measuring noise:

I'm **fairly** certain what you're dealing with is just memory caching from a previous (implicit)matlab operation speeding it up.  I rewrote your naive implementation to use a lookup table (so it's a straightforward assignment with no type conversion).  That did not speed it up any.  That's worth noting.

Next, I ran a similar (but different--to keep it from being optimized away) loop and timed that.  It ran *much* faster:

```
int main()
{
  float index[65537] ;
  for (int i = 0; i < 65537; i++)
    index[i] = i;
  uint16_t *pi = new uint16_t[4096 * 1000];
  memset(pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
  float *pf = new float[4096 * 1000];
  memset(pf, 0, sizeof(pf));
  clock_t begin = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4096 * 1000; ++i)
  {
    pf[i] = index[pi[i]]; //no conversion...simple copy(and not faster)
  }
  clock_t end = clock();
  clock_t begin2 = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4096 * 1000; ++i)
  {
    pf[i] = index[pi[i]+1]; 
  }
  clock_t end2 = clock();
  printf("%d\n", (long)end - begin);
  printf("%d\n", (long)end2 - begin2);
}
```

Output:

```
9
2
```

I got similar results with an actual float conversion.  So my theory is that Matlab is simply performing some operation that's getting important memory cached before performing the operation you are timing (which you are probably using a different mechanism to time, by the way).

This is all guesswork, but that's probably the best you're going to get without a matlab expert dropping in.

Output from the above in `C#`, btw:  `12, 4`.